# Adding build with parameters inside a stage?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I know in a jenkins pipeline, we can set build with parameters at the top level of the Jenkinsfile , so that the Jenkins asks for parameters, before the build is initiated.

My question is, can this **build with parameters step** be added in a specific stage, and then the stage proceeds based on these values,

I mean for example,

```
pipeline {
    node any 
    stages {
       stage('stage1') {
          steps {
              ....
              ....
         }
       }
       stage('build with parameters') {
              steps {

              properties([gitLabConnection('Gitlab'), 
             [$class: 'RebuildSettings', autoRebuild: false, 
              rebuildDisabled: false], 

              parameters([booleanParam(defaultValue: true, description: 'Do we need this option?', name: 'option1'), 

              booleanParam(defaultValue: false, description: 'Do we need this option?', name: 'option2')
           ])
       ])

       proceed based on above option

       }
    }
     stage('stage 3') {
      steps {
            ......
            ......
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any help ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you require is the input step:
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/